# Cron job error: accessing Datastore and emailing

Tags: python, google-app-engine, cron

For my web app, I wrote this cron job that is supposed to access data in the Google App Engine's Datastore, parse a website, then email the results.

However, I get a `404` error when requesting the cron job, and don't know how to fix this. Is it the way I'm accessing the database?

Thanks

Here's my `update.py`:

```
from google.appengine.ext import db

import urllib2
import string

import myWebapp

## CRON 1:                                                                      
## Check all x in B.db if courses changed                                   
##  Yes:                                                                        
##    email x                                                                   
##    if x.things all != 'Closed':                                             
##        remove from db                                                        

boo = myWebapp.B.all()

if boo.count() >0:
    for b in boo.run(batch_size=1000):
        currentThings = b.mThings
        newThings = myWebapp.updateStatus(b.mThings)
        if currentThings != newThings:
            b.mThings = newThings
            myWebapp.sendTextAndEmail(b.mEmail, b.mPhoneNumMail,
                         b.mThings, "myWebapp Update")
        numClosed = 0
        for c in b.mThings:          
            if c[2] == 'Closed':
                numClosed += 1
        if numClosed == 0:
            b.delete()
```

Here's my cron.yaml:

```
cron:
- description: check things and email if change
  url: /.update.py
  schedule: every 5 minutes
  timezone: US/Pacific
```

Answer (score 0):

The docs note:

> To test a cron job, sign in as an administrator and visit the URL of the handler in your browser.

[Securing URLS for CRON](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/cron#Securing_URLs_for_Cron)

If you still get a 404 suggest you make a "normal" handler and take it from there.

The way you are accessing the database or otherwise is not relevant to a 404 (not found) error.

Comment: What do you mean by making a normal handler? Declare a RequestHandler within update.py, as well as: app = webapp2.WSGIApplication('/update.py', update)?

Comment: yeah, make a normal handler then go to it. If that works, convert it into your cron handler.